# Handling events from a gtkwidget built from an XML file

Tags: c, graphics, gtk

I am writing a graphics program in C where I have a GTK window built from an XML file. This window has a few buttons and handlers corresponding to each(for example if the button says "circle" then there is a handler called "on_circle_clicked()"). I want to handle events when these buttons are clicked. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using GTK (C API), or GTKmm (C++ bindings) ?

Comment: I am using GTK. This is the code:

Comment: void initGuiWindow()
{        
    
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "assignment1gui.xml", (GError**)NULL);
    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);  

    
    
       
}

Answer (score 2):

The signal handling code goes in your signal handler. As per your example if you button "circle" which has a signal handler for "clicked" as "on_circle_clicked", then when the button is clicked on_circle_clicked will be called & this will have the logic to handle click on that button. To do this using [glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) (which generates the kind of xml file which you are using) is by add names of signal handlers for the widget while creating the xml file. These signal handlers then will have to be implemented in your source code. You might find [these](http://clockwork.fr/2011/05/gtk-glade-and-signal-handlers/) [links](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4702) useful. Please find below sample for your reference:
sample.c

```
/* Compile as :gcc sample.c  -Wall -Wextra -Wl,--export-dynamic `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-export-2.0` -o sample */
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void on_circle_clicked(GtkButton * b, gpointer data)
{
    (void)b;
    (void)data;
    printf(" Circle clicked\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GError *err = NULL;
    const char *builder_file = "sample.glade";

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    if (gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, builder_file, &err) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error adding builder from file %s\n%s\n",
            builder_file, err->message);
        return -1;
    }
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window"));
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, " Object window not found\n");
        return -2;
    }
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

sample.glade

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Glade sample</property>
    <property name="has_resize_grip">False</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="gtk_main_quit" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="circle">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">circle</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
        <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
        <signal name="clicked" handler="on_circle_clicked" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Things you should be careful about:

1. As mentioned in the documentation for [`gtk_builder_connect_signals`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-connect-signals), you should compile your program with `-Wl,--export-dynamic` C flags on Linux/Unix & link against `gmodule-export-2.0`. On Windows you need to add `G_MODULE_EXPORT` before your signal handler.
2. As the signal handler symbol is looked up, *don't* make it as a `static` function or *hide* the function (for instance setting visibility attribute for function as "hidden" with gcc)

Hope this helps!